# Populate data in a gridview using multiple selection in listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to populate data in a gridview using multiple selection from a listview?

This is my code for the gridview

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT employee.Empno, employee.Dptno, employee.Grade, employee.Employee FROM employee INNER JOIN grade ON employee.Grade = grade.Grade INNER JOIN empskill ON employee.Empno = empskill.Empno WHERE (empskill.Skillno = @Skillno)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListBox1" Name="Skillno" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but the problem i'm having is that the data is not from all the selected rows in the listview.

The listview is a list of skills and the data populated in the gridview is the employees who posses these skills selected in the listbox.  So if you select 2 skills, it should display the employees who has BOTH the selected skills not combined them.  Hope that makes my question clear.

Comment: Do you have a constraint on using the `SqlDataSource`? I say that because you're about to open up a very large worm hole. What you're trying to do requires a custom adapter, and to further that, the list box items aren't serializable so you'll have to cache them and leverage that cache inside your custom adapter.

Comment: your existing query will only work for a single selection. you need to look at dynamically building the Select statement based on the selected ListView Values also what's to stop the user from selecting more than 2 itesm. you also don't have any code or logic from what I can see, if the user decides to select no Items from the ListView..

Comment: That's what I need help with, to build the Select statement to display skills possess by ALL employees selected not adding it all together.